# VSCode's Jupyter Notebook: environment variables mysteriously loads from .env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

I'm using VSCode's Jupyter Notebook extension. I'm trying to figure out how environment variables get magically loaded from an .env file. I'm not using `python-dotenv` or doing anything special to load these variables, but it just seems to work.

Here's what I did.

```
mkdir testing
cd testing
python -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
touch .env
```

Inside of a new `.env` file, I added this:

```
FOO=bar
```

Then inside of a notebook, magic:

[image]

Anyone know how this is possible? Is this only a VSCode thing (i.e. open this notebook in another tool and env variables won't load)?

Tested in macOS and Windows and they both behave the same.

Comment: Looks like a unique behavior of jupyter in vscode, I opened a [discussion here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/13881) you can follow.

Comment: You can also take a look at this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20932).

Comment: @JialeDu fantastic, thank you. I'll mark this question as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JialeDu, the answer is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/13881

Specifically:

> Both Jupyter and Python extensions automatically load .env files in the following scenarios (there could be others as well):
>
> - running notebooks (jupyter extension)
> - Running code in Interactive window (jupyter extension)
> - Debugging Python code in python files (python extension)